# What is the accepted syntax for PySpark's SQL expression-based filters?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, syntax, apache-spark-sql

The [PySpark documentation for filters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html) says that it accepts "a string of SQL expression".

Is there a reference of the accepted syntax for this parameter? The best I could find is the page about the [WHERE clause](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-where.html) in Spark SQL docs. Obviously some examples, like `"id > 200"`, `"length(name) > 3"`, or `"id BETWEEN 200 AND 300"`, would work. But what about others? Filters like `"age > (SELECT 42)"` seem to work, so I assume nested expressions are OK. This just raises more questions:

- What databases can these nested expressions refer to? Is there a way I can create a nested `SELECT` expression referring to the current dataframe, e.g. to do something like `"age > (SELECT avg(age) FROM <current_dataframe>)"` as a filter? (I know there are other ways of achieving this, I am only interested in what SQL expressions can do.)
- Are there other, more advanced things that are allowed in filter expressions?
- Finally, is there an online resource explaining this in more detail?

Comment: A lot of questions. What triggered them?

Comment: My team is building a library on top of Spark (to do differential privacy). We support filters, and simply pass the string argument directly to Spark. I would like to have good documentation for this method, and I find PySpark's documentation (which, ideally, I would want to simply link to) a bit lacking.